# how to import an existing database into SQL server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I am brand new to SQL, SQL Server 2012 and SQL Databases. I have an example database already created for me that I want to import into my SQL Server. 
[image: Books database]

I notice that there is a Books_log with it too. What is it? (I appreciate your answer but not my main question tho).

I've tried importing it by using SQL Server Management Studio. I created a new database, then I right-clicked it and selected Tasks, then Import Data, then the Import and Export Wizard Opened, then I gave it my best guess and selected Flat File Source as my Data Source, then I clicked on Browse and selected the Books.mdf database. Then at this point I feel like there is something wrong because when I moved to the Columns or Preview tab this is what it looks like:
[image: Columns view]

Anyways, I clicked on Next. I chose the .Net Framwork Data Provider for SqlServer as my Destination. Then clicked on Next and this is what I got:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Books_log is the log file for the database, i.e. all changes you make to the database are logged to be able to rollback, etc. To be able to use an existing mdf, you can use attach, right click on "Databases", click attach and select your mdf.

[image]

Comment: That seems to be taking me to toward the right path except, I am getting this now... Unable to open the physical file... Access denied

Comment: @AleAng That I can't really help much with, copy the files to your local HDD, make sure you have access to them, make sure you are not trying to open the mdf the other database is using, no other process is accessing them, etc, could be a number of reasons but the error pretty much sums it up.

Comment: @AleAng. Access denied...as in error 5? Or insufficient rights? Note that the SQL Server INSTANCE needs rights to the path. Then there must exist the correct login and finally the user must have the correct roles (like db_datawriter) granted in order to work.

Comment: Problem solved by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060441/cannot-install-adventureworks-2012-database-operating-system-error-5-access-i

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways.  One of the easier ways is to create a backup, copy the backup file to the other server, then restore the backup. Remember tot check the box in the restore screen that sways "Overwrite any existing database"